# sizeof works unusual at c++ after array creation

Tags: c++, arrays, sizeof

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find the sizeof(a pointer pointing to an array)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492384/how-to-find-the-sizeofa-pointer-pointing-to-an-array)

I am creating an array by using following code

```
float *A;
A = (float *) malloc(100*sizeof(float));
float *B;
B = (float *) malloc(100*sizeof(float));
```

but after these when I type an print the size of the A and B by the following, I get 2 as a result as I expect to see 100.

```
sizeof(A)/sizeof(float)
```

Comment: use `std::vector`

Comment: Your expectation, that the size of a pointer should change if you change what it's pointing to, is unreasonable. (Now, if this was an array passed to a function, you'd have a point.)

Comment: -1 solely for being moronic to helpful experts in comments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works only for static arrays, defined in the current scope.

All you get in your example is the size of a pointer to `float` divided by the size of `float`.

Answer (score 11):

Your expectation is wrong. `A` is a `float*`, so its size will be `sizeof(float*)`, regardless of how you actually allocate it.

If you had a static array - i.e. `float A[100]`, then this would work.

Since this is C++, use `std::array` or `std::vector`.

Worst case, use `new[]`. **Definitely don't use `malloc`.**

Comment: so no way to get the size ?

Comment: @Erogol there would be if you took good advice and stop writing C code and labeling it C++. Use `vector` or `array`.

Comment: I think best is to learn C and stop scripting with toy languages...

Comment: @Erogol, just store the size in a variable or use higher-level C++ constructs

Comment: @Erogol so, wait, do you want to learn C or C++? You do know they're different, right?

Comment: @Erogol, if you want to learn C, then learn it. But why do you tag your question with `C++` tag then? Don't you know that C and C++ are different languages?

Comment: @Erogol If you tag your question `C++`, expect C++ answers.

Comment: Ohh man are these different? I should have realized that before as their difference on the names? You enlightened on me ? Regards for all your bright minds?

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel I would say f*ck off but it is not appropriate

Comment: @Erogol Sorry, you can't have an account here if you're under 13.

Comment: @Erogol Stop throwing tantrums like a spoiled stubborn child. You got your answer already. Annoy and insult more people who try to help you even though they don't have to, see how well that goes~

Comment: @Erogol: "Ban me out" isn't English. 1 year, 10 months on Stack Overflow should be enough time to learn English.